# Set font format for point label in ASP.NET Chart control

Tags: asp.net, charts

Im working with MS chart control .net 4.0

```
CharTemp.Series[seriesName].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
CharTemp.Series[seriesName].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Line;
```

My chart may show 3-4 series depend on input data so i want to change the Forecolor of point label as the same as serie's line color.
Please tell me if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

```
chartSellInArea.Series["AttaintoForecast"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chartSellInArea.Series["AttaintoForecast"].Color = Color.Orange;
chartSellInArea.Series["AttaintoForecast"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
chartSellInArea.Series["AttaintoForecast"].LabelBackColor = Color.Orange;
```